# append properties file from java

Tags: java, properties

From java I want to read .properties file and if property is present I want to re-set the property again. lets say .properties file has entry password=123 now I want to check If password entry is there replace 123 with 567. but need to keep all content as it is. how to do that? please help

Comment: Can you give a visual example?

Comment: Your question seems to contain a logic fallacy: It is not possible logically to change a file and keep it unchanged at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of rightaway is

1. Load all the properties from the base .properties file.
2. Create a new temp properties file and loop through the entries from original file to write the same in to new file. In the loop you can change the value of any property while writing it to a new file.
3. After the loop delete the original file and rename the temp file as original file.

This approach has couple of limitations,

1. Do not use it if you are really concerned about the file last modified/created date, since we are creating a whole new file here.
2. If the original file is too big, this approach may cause memory problems.

Hope this helps!